# Wierd reflections on reflective surface

Tags: reflection

im new to blender and want to ask your help. I have this kind of issue:(tabel top made from 2 different pieces) 2 different objects reflecting light in a strange way. Can you help me figure out what i have done wrong and how i can fix it. (maybe i messed up with scaling when modeled this)

PS. Thank you, for help
[image]

[image: **enter image description here**]

Comment: No enough edge loop for the top to smooth the normal correctly

Comment: Thanks for anwser, but it doesnt helped, main thing that bothers me, that reflections on table not matching. Left table part reflecting light like it is far from it, but right side reflecting like its close to the light source. Otherwise on the right side reflection of the object is bigger then it should be

Comment: Change it to flat shading rather smooth shading. If it fixes the problem, then will be normal direction problem.

Comment: thx. everything solved )))